# How do I change Java platform in MacOS preferences?

Tags: java, macos, version

I'm using a tool that requires at least Java 11. I have installed java 17 and put it on my bash_profile using the function JAVA_HOME. When I run

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I correctly get

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
```

However, the tool I'm using does not open and I get the following message:

REQUIRES AT LEAST JAVA 11 BUT YOU ARE RUNNING JAVA 1.8

In fact, if I check on Java settings in Mac Preferences, I get that the installed version is the suggested version Java 8 update 371. Looking under 'platform' I also have 1.8 with this position

java.sun.com

and this path

/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

How can I let my computer know that I have Java 17 so that I can use my tool?

Comment: I shall make a generic comment as I don't use MacOS. But the first thing you could do is `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME\bin:$PATH"` Now run your tool from that terminal. If that works for you then you can write that below where you successfully set `JAVA_HOME`